# Using android's native Camera App to capture photos throws SecurityException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to take photo from android device's native Camera App. For that i create a file first and then attach its URI with the intent to capture image and write output in that file.
For file provider i have added the following in the AndroidManifest file

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

And the java code for capturing image is as follows

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mActivity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            String imageName = "image_" + Preferences.getStringForUserId(mActivity);
            photoFile = createImageFile(imageName);
            mCurrentPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            try {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    String authorities = "com.example.myapp.fileprovider";
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mActivity, authorities, photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

                } else {
                    Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                }
                mActivity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_CODE);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No Camera App found in device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

As documented in Android own documentation by Google in: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
I have added necessary permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But did not add permission for Camera and i am also asking for runtime permissions for Android M or higher.
Getting from the Google docs it is clear that we do not need Camera Permission if we want to use native Camera App to capture photos for our App, then why does it give me this exception stated below

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Pictures/myapp/image_20130-1383873550.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{d82d864 6641:com.pencilinapp.pencilin/u0a63} (pid=6641, uid=10063) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA

So my question is that do i have to ask for both Camera and Storage permissions from now on? And why is it not stated in Google Documentation?

I have researched and checked many stackoverflow threads but none gave answer related to this issue so far.

Comment: "Getting from the Google docs it is clear that we do not need Camera Permission if we want to use native Camera App to capture photos for our App" - are you sure?

Comment: as i have also given link please see this 
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
There is no mention of adding Camera permission

Comment: Google says - If you are using the camera by invoking an existing camera app, your application does not need to request this permission. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: @ShaluTD and in almost all blogs that i have visited for adding Image capturing feature from Camera App, i have seen that they add only Storage Permissions, i did that as well and my App was working fine for a time (maybe permission had been granted from App settings, idk..) but recently when i checked my Image Capturing feature, it started to give me this Exception

Comment: i think u have confused it with taking Images using Camera API. No i am not using camera API, i'm just leveraging Android's Camera App. And i have seen this doc too. And yeah of course Google says that "If you are using the camera by invoking an existing camera app, your application does not need to request this permission", so they why does it give SecurityException now? thats what i wanna know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the revoked permission ("with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA"). Normally, you do not need permission, but if you *ask* for permission (say, in a previous build of your app), and the user revokes that permission, then you cannot use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Okay so what i am getting is that before i asked for this permission in some previous build and i (as a user) may have denied it, so now it is giving me this Exception, right? 
Then what must be its solution?

Comment: @Faizy_Flash: In terms of your app, don't ask for the `CAMERA` permission anymore. In terms of existing installations, either grant the permission via the Settings app or reinstall the app.

Comment: okay thanks, one more question, if i still dont use this permission 
'<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />' 
should i just check programmatically check if it is granted or not and then ask to allow it from permission settings for old users?

Comment: @Faizy_Flash: Well, you may need that permission. I don't know where you have set up `FileProvider` to write the photo.

Comment: Oh sorry i meant... 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 should i add it or not? Yeah i just edited my question and added the file provider code. And i just reinstalled the App on emulator, running Android M, without camera permission and it still gave that Exception. 
Sorry for bothering too much but i still don't seem to find its fix

Comment: and in the Settings it is still showing that my App requires Camera permission

Comment: @Faizy_Flash: " should i add it or not? " -- do not add that permission.

Comment: i created a new emulator running Android N and installed app with no Cam permission anywhere, and only asked for storage permissions, but it still threw that SecurityException. And it is showing Camera permission in the App permission setting of the emulator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167782/discussion-between-faizy-flash-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 1):

However, not all Android devices actually have these hardware features. So if your app requests the CAMERA permission, it's important that you also include the `<uses-feature>` tag in your manifest to declare whether or not this feature is actually required.
For more information, see [Google Play and feature-based filtering](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#market-feature-filtering)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your package" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

From Marshmallow, Dangerous permissions are:

1. READ_CALENDAR
2. WRITE_CALENDAR
3. **CAMERA**
4. READ_CONTACTS
5. WRITE_CONTACTS
6. GET_ACCOUNTS
7. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
8. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
9. RECORD_AUDIO
10. READ_PHONE_STATE
11. CALL_PHONE
12. READ_CALL_LOG
13. WRITE_CALL_LOG
14. ADD_VOICEMAIL
15. USE_SIP
16. PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
17. BODY_SENSORS
18. SEND_SMS
19. RECEIVE_SMS
20. READ_SMS
21. RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
22. RECEIVE_MMS
23. READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
24. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

SO i think Permission may be required...

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in your **Manifest.xml** :

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Please refer to this [URL](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest) for more.