# Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity }

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Please help! Camera cannot open when i click it. I'm using android M, maybe that's the problem. please help me how to open the camera...
I'm trying to add some permission but it still doesn't work. I'm already use `

but it still doesn't work. please help

**this is my code**

```
public class TambahLaporActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Integer REQUEST_CAMERA = 1, SELECT_FILE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tambah_lapor);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        CardView imageView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv);
        //set a clickListener on that view
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SelectImage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void SelectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TambahLaporActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Image");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (items[i].equals("Camera")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

                } else if (items[i].equals("Gallery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Type"), SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[i].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requenstCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requenstCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requenstCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else if (requenstCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire Java stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: @CommonsWare it says with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534463/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare do you know what code should I write?

Comment: Your code is fine (other than calling `setImageURI()`, which is a separate issue). Remove the `CAMERA` permission from your manifest. Then, fully uninstall the app, before running the app again.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue for me it's related to the manifest dependency. I added Camera permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and that creates issues in build formation i.e.

```
Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity }
```

And then I just removed that user permission and added this user feature

```
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
```

And that magically works for me. I hope that can help anyone else also.